# Download a .asp / .asx video file (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, video, command-line, download, flash

My [local TV station](http://www.iba.org.il/media/?recorded=recorded1) offers [streaming video of recorded documentaries](http://switch3.castup.net/cunet/gm.asp?ai=31&ar=10_1_2010-05-12_231121), using a XML-like file with a`.asx` extension.

Is there a way (preferably Ubuntu CLI) to download the file?

Thanks,

Adam

PS - the file contents:

```
<asx version="3.0">
        <!-- GMX -->
        <param name="encoding" value="utf-8" />
        <title>CastUP: V0109-msheni-Hayim_Hefer-120510                   </title>
        <MOREINFO HREF = "" />

        <PARAM NAME="Prebuffer" VALUE="true" />
        <entry>

        <ref href="http://s3awm.castup.net/server12/31/176/17607833-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />

        <ref href="http://s0dwm.castup.net/server12/31/176/17607833-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />

        <ref href="http://s0ewm.castup.net/server12/31/176/17607833-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />

        <ref href="http://s0fwm.castup.net/server12/31/176/17607833-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />

        <ref href="http://s0gwm.castup.net/server12/31/176/17607833-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />
        <PARAM NAME="CanSkipBack" VALUE="No"/>
<PARAM NAME="CanSkipForward" VALUE="No"/>
<PARAM NAME="CanSeek" VALUE="No"/>
<title>mondial_2010                                      </title>

        <PARAM NAME="Prebuffer" VALUE="true" />

        <PARAM NAME="CastUP_Content_Config" VALUE="" />
        </entry>

        <entry>
        <PARAM NAME="EntryType" VALUE="Content" />

        <param name="encoding" value="utf-8" />
        <PARAM NAME="CastUP_AssociatedURL" VALUE="" />
        <PARAM NAME="CastUP_Content_Config" VALUE="" />
        <PARAM NAME="CastUP_Content_ClipMediaID" VALUE="5382858" />
        <author>iba</author>
                <title>CastUP: V0109-msheni-Hayim_Hefer-120510                   </title>

        <PARAM NAME="Prebuffer" VALUE="true" />
<ref href="mms://s3awm.castup.net/server12/31/174/17482045-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />
<ref href="mms://s0dwm.castup.net/server12/31/174/17482045-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />
<ref href="mms://s0ewm.castup.net/server12/31/174/17482045-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />
<ref href="mms://s0fwm.castup.net/server12/31/174/17482045-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />
<ref href="mms://s0gwm.castup.net/server12/31/174/17482045-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491" />

        </entry>

</asx>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `mimms` and then you can download the streams with, for instance:

```
mimms 'mms://s3awm.castup.net/server12/31/174/17482045-61.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=31&ts=0&cu=91A297E2-5359-416A-912B-2D9BC106E491'
```

Note: I'm using the quotes because the shell will interpret the `?` and `&` characters if I don't.